# Collapsible list - Collapsing multiple list items with separate toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slidetoggle

I found [some jquery code](http://www.rvamedia.com/wordpress/collapsible-responsive-menu-for-genesis) to be able to have a collapsible sub menu in a list.

When I apply this code:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').prepend('<a id="fa-menu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>');
$("#fa-menu").on("click", function(){
    $(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

I am able to expand and collapse, but it does so for every instance of `.sub-menu` and only allows me to toggle with the first `#fa-menu` instance.

See [my website](http://www.jmalais.com/) for an example.

How do I get it to toggle separate from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$(".sub-menu").slideToggle();` Use `$(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();`, Call preventDefault() if you want to stop propagation.

Comment: This will now only toggle the first sub menu, how would I allow for toggling of subsequent menus?